# Not getting any output even if there is no race conditions

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I am trying to create producer-consumer message queue system in Golang using buffered channel. Here is my implementation.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type MessageQueue struct {
    storage chan int
    count   int
}

var done = make(chan bool)

func NewMessageQueue(count int) *MessageQueue {
    ret := &MessageQueue{
        count:   count,
        storage: make(chan int, count),
    }
    return ret
}

func (m *MessageQueue) Produce() {
    for i := 0; i < m.count; i++ {
        m.storage <- i + 1
    }
    done <- true
}

func (m *MessageQueue) Consume(f func(int) int) {
    for each := range m.storage {
        fmt.Printf("%d ", f(each))
    }
}

func main() {
    op1 := func(a int) int {
        return a * a
    }
    msq := NewMessageQueue(10)
    go msq.Produce()
    go msq.Consume(op1)
    <-done
}
```

But unfortunately, I am not able to get the output when I run `go run main.go` however to check if there is any race condition or not, when I try `go run -race main.go`, I do get the output. I am unable to understand why it is happening. Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When your producer can send the values, it sends a value on the `done` channel so your app can terminate immediately.

Instead when the producer is done, it should close the `m.storage` channel, signalling no more values will be sent, and do not send a value on `done`, as you're not done!

You're done when values are consumed, so send a value on `done` in `Consume()`:

```
func (m *MessageQueue) Produce() {
    for i := 0; i < m.count; i++ {
        m.storage <- i + 1
    }
    close(m.storage)
}

func (m *MessageQueue) Consume(f func(int) int) {
    for each := range m.storage {
        fmt.Printf("%d ", f(each))
    }
    done <- true
}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/CySMLaY5Cz-)):

```
1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100
```

The `done` channel is required because consuming does not happen in the `main` goroutine, and the `main` goroutine must wait for it to end.

If you do the consuming on the `main` goroutine, you can remove the `done` channel:

```
msq := NewMessageQueue(10)
go msq.Produce()
msq.Consume(op1)
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/XlfJ6s1DH2w).

Comment: Oh great. Is there any way that don't use the `done` channel extra and use the closing signal in the consumer with the select poll ?

Comment: @MayukhSarkar It's required if consuming does not happen on the `main` goroutine. But it's not needed otherwise. See edited answer.